# Find last day of previous week

Tags: sql-server, date

I am trying to figure out how to compute the last day of the previous week in SQL Server. The report that I'm running might be run on any day, Monday thru Friday, so finding that date can't hinge on any particular day of the week. The last day of the previous week is Friday (no business is done on Saturday) but if, for the sake of simplicity, Saturday is counted as the last day of the week (not sure if that's standard in SQL Server) that's fine too.

Answer (score 0):

you can substitute GETDATE() with the actual date field on your query

```
SELECT DATEADD(day,-1 - (DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST - 1) % 7,GETDATE()) -1 AS 'LastSaturday'
```

Comment: Question: Where is @@DATEFIRST coming from? I am not using any variables in the View I'm creating in SQL Server.

Comment: its a setting in sql server. Details in the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15. The query will bring the result set regardless of the actual DATEFIRST setting value